# What does a stream do with any fetched data before a 'data' callback is registered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

The following example uses `curl` (assuming it exists in the system) to download a file specified by `file_url`.

`spawn()` returns a stream of the result of invoking `curl` with the passed arguments. `curl.stdout.on` will register a callback that will be called as curl streams the chunks of data to our application upon which we will `write` these chunks of data to `file`, which is a `WriteStream`.

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name)
var curl = spawn('curl', [file_url])

curl.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
  file.write(data)
})

curl.stdout.on('end', function(data) {
  file.end()
})
```

What would happen if as soon as `spawn` was invoked, but before the `on("data", [Function])` calback is registered, `curl` has already fetched and come back with some of the data?

As I finished typing this question I had the *epiphany* that the internal stream implementation should simply buffer / collect all these chunks of data as they come and only emit `'data'` events if a `'data'` callback is registered.

Can you confirm this and / or explain where I am mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that Node.js is single threaded. Any messages coming from the curl process will get "queued" and be emitted once Javascript gives it a chance.   So since you're registering your `on('data'...` callback right after that, you're not giving javascript a chance to emit any data. If you used a `setTimeout` to then set the `on('data'...` callback then yes you may miss some data.

test.bat

```
echo "Hello!"
```

---

No Data Loss:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var curl = spawn('test.bat');

console.log('before');
for (var i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++) {
        //Waste some time
}
console.log('after');

curl.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('data: ' + data);
});

curl.stdout.on('end', function (data) {
    console.log('end: ' + data);
});

setTimeout(function () { }, 10000); //Just to keep console open for 10 seconds
```

---

Data Loss:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var curl = spawn('test.bat');

setTimeout(function () { 
    curl.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('data: ' + data);
    });

    curl.stdout.on('end', function (data) {
        console.log('end: ' + data);
    });

    console.log('finished');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. That means my insight is incorrect, but clearly explains why there is no data loss in the above code snippet. What would happen if I do something like `setTimeout(cbThatRegistersOnData, 0)`?

Comment: If you used a timeout (0ms) then you **might** lose some data. Processes take time to start (maybe an entire second) so I doubt you'd lose data when using a timeout of 0ms, but you're running into a race condition. And just because you use a timeout of 0ms doesn't mean another part of your code doesn't use a dumb for loop (like above) which waits a second or more and causes you to register after data has been emitted.